# mongoose .findByIdAndUpdate() is not updating the document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, resolver

I'm using GraphQL with MongoDB and I can't seem to update product names that I've added to the database. Currently, there is no front-end to worry about and I'm just trying to get this working in Apollo Studio. When I run this mutation it returns the correct product object but does not update the name field. It seems to be ignoring the new name I've input entirely.

Resolver

```
updateProductName: async (parent, { id, newName }) => {
      const product = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(
        id,
        { name: newName },
        { new: true }
      );

      return product;
    },
```

typeDef

```
updateProductName(id: String!, name: String!): Product!
```

Comment: Can you try `findOneAndUpdate({ id }, { name: newName }, { new: true });`

Comment: If you run a find for that product afterward, does it show the update?

Comment: No, it does not. I suspected that initially but the update doesn't occur no matter how many times I run the mutation.